# ArcPy intersection method passing in two polygon features returns an inaccessible line feature object

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to calculate the area of two overlapping surface elements in order to calculate the area overlap between them.

Then I used the intersect method to get the overlapping area of polygon A and polygon B. I used 'intersect.area' to access the area of the overlapping area, which was always zero, causing me to be unable to proceed to the next step in my calculations, so I looked at the type of the geometric object returned after using the intersect method, and found that the type was polyline.

The specific code is as follows:

```
# 计算面积重叠率
    def area_overlap_ratio(geometry_a, geometry_b):
        intersection = geometry_a.intersect(geometry_b, 2)
        print(type(intersection))
        area_a = geometry_a.area
        area_b = geometry_b.area
        overlap_area = intersection.area

        overlap_ratio = overlap_area / math.sqrt(area_a * area_b)

        return overlap_ratio
```

The output is of type <class 'arcpy.arcobjects.geometries.Polyline'>.
So I tried to convert this polyline element to a polygon element, but both reported errors. The errors are RuntimeError: 'in_table' is not a table or a featureclass, i.e. intersection is not a valid element class or table.

How can I solve this problem or convert this line element to a face element?

Comment: What types are geometry_a and geometry_b? Check they are in fact polygons.  Per the documentation, intersect returns the lowest dimension shape based on the inputs.  [Intersect, arcpy](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm#:~:text=If%20the%20inputs,will%20be%20polygon.)

Comment: The geometry_a and geometry_b are the geometry objects I passed in, which simply represent a variable name. Also I don't quite understand this minimum dimension you are talking about, because face elements using intersect can only be 2.@evv_gis

Comment: Similar to line 3 of your code snippet, I was suggesting you check the type to see if the variables are in fact polygons as well.  If you intersect two different geometry types, the result will always be geometry type with the least amount of dimensions.  Points have less dimensions than Lines, Lines have less dimensions than Polygons.  If you are getting a polyline, then your input geometries contain at least one polyline type.

Comment: The intersection of two polygons which only touch along an edge is a line. It would not be possible to convert this line to a polygon because it is a *line*, not a ring. You need to test for and handle the condition where there is no overlap.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solved my problem.@evv_gis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explicitly requested a Linestring result by specifying

```py
intersection = geometry_a.intersect(geometry_b, 2)
```

when you should have specified:

```py
intersection = geometry_a.intersect(geometry_b, 4)
```

The `dimension` parameter is [documented](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/geometry.htm) as being one of values {1,2,4} (bitmasks of 2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>), with 4 as two-dimensional (polygon):

[image]

Using the test code:

```py
import arcpy

srid = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
srid.setFalseOriginAndUnits(-400.0,-400.0,1000000.0)

p1 = arcpy.FromWKT("POLYGON (( 0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))",srid)
p2 = arcpy.FromWKT("POLYGON (( 0 1, 0 2, 1 1, 0 1))",srid)
p3 = arcpy.FromWKT("POLYGON (( 0 0, 0 2, 1 1, 0 0))",srid)

shp = p1.intersect(p2,4)
print("p1(p{:d},{:d}) : {:s}".format(2,4,shp.WKT))

shp = p1.intersect(p2,2)
print("p1(p{:d},{:d}) : {:s}".format(2,2,shp.WKT))

shp = p1.intersect(p3,4)
print("p1(p{:d},{:d}) : {:s}".format(3,4,shp.WKT))

shp = p1.intersect(p3,2)
print("p1(p{:d},{:d}) : {:s}".format(3,2,shp.WKT))
```

I got the result:

```
p1(p2,4) : MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY
p1(p2,2) : MULTILINESTRING ((0 1, 1 1))
p1(p3,4) : MULTIPOLYGON (((1 1, 0 1, 0 0, 1 1)))
p1(p3,2) : MULTILINESTRING ((1 1, 0 0, 0 1))
```

This shows that the Polyline result does not contain the closing point (and the order is incorrect for a Polygon, though that would be automatically corrected). This is the reason that the attempt to convert the Polyline to Polygon fails. (Personally, I'd consider the missing vertex on the Polyline a bug, but it doesn't seem like something worth pursuing, when you can get a Polygon by asking for it.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solved my problem, thank you very much, contact me if you need help in the future!@Vince respect!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can achieve your goal much easier with the Summarize Within (Analysis) tool. With it you can save the intermediate step with Intersect.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm

You may also be interested in Apportion Polygon (Analysis).

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/apportion-polygon.htm

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solved my problem.@Xeppit